# Export arabic data into pdf asp.net showing error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

When I export ARABIC data into pdf.Microsoft adobereader showing error.Adobe reader could not open file because it is either not a supported file.My code is following asp.net c#.Guide me

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
            doc.Open();

            //Sample HTML
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append(@"<p>This is a test: <strong>مسندم</strong></p>");

            //Path to our font
            string arialuniTff = Server.MapPath("~/tradbdo.TTF");
            //Register the font with iTextSharp
            iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(arialuniTff);

            //Create a new stylesheet
            iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
            //Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
            ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Traditional Arabic Bold");
            //Set the default encoding to support Unicode characters
            ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

            //Parse our HTML using the stylesheet created above
            List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString()), ST);

            //Loop through each element, don't bother wrapping in P tags
            foreach (var element in list)
            {
                doc.Add(element);
            }

            doc.Close();
            Response.Write(doc);
            Response.End();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following article which shows how to correctly export and display Arabic content via the iTextSharp library: http://geekswithblogs.net/JaydPage/archive/2011/11/02/using-itextsharp-to-correctly-display-hebrew--arabic-text-right.aspx.

Here is the code sample that you can try:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

public void WriteDocument()
{
   //Declare a itextSharp document
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    //Create our file stream and bind the writer to the document and the stream
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"C:\Test.Pdf", FileMode.Create));

    //Open the document for writing
    document.Open();

   //Add a new page
    document.NewPage();

    //Reference a Unicode font to be sure that the symbols are present.
    BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    //Create a font from the base font
    Font font = new Font(bfArialUniCode, 12);

    //Use a table so that we can set the text direction
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    //Ensure that wrapping is on, otherwise Right to Left text will not display
    table.DefaultCell.NoWrap = false;

    //Create a regex expression to detect hebrew or arabic code points
    const string regex_match_arabic_hebrew = @"[\u0600-\u06FF,\u0590-\u05FF]+";
    if (Regex.IsMatch("مسندم", regex_match_arabic_hebrew, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
    }

    //Create a cell and add text to it
    PdfPCell text = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("مسندم", font));
    //Ensure that wrapping is on, otherwise Right to Left text will not display
    text.NoWrap = false;

    //Add the cell to the table
    table.AddCell(text);

    //Add the table to the document
    document.Add(table);

    //Close the document
    document.Close();

    //Launch the document if you have a file association set for PDF's
    Process AcrobatReader = new Process();
    AcrobatReader.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Test.Pdf";
    AcrobatReader.Start();

}
```

Comment: this is not working. I have tried this sample from geekswithblogs

Answer (score 0):

The `iTextSharp.text.Document` is a class used to help bridge human concepts like `Paragraph` and `Margin` into PDF concepts. The *bridge* part is important. It is ***not*** a PDF file in any way so it should never be treated as a PDF. Doing so would be like treating `System.Drawing.Graphics` as if it were an image. This leads to one of your problems on the second to last line of code that tries to treat the `Document` as if it were a PDF by sending it directly to the output stream:

```
//This won't work
Response.Write(doc);
```

You will find many, many tutorials out there that do this and they are all wrong. Fortunately (or unfortunately), PDF is forgiving and allows junk data at the end so only a handful of PDF fail and people assume there was some other problem.

Your other problem is that you are missing a `PdfWriter`. If `Document` is the bridge, `PdfWriter` is the actual construction worker that puts that PDF together. It, however, is also not a PDF. Instead, it needs to be bound to a stream like a file, in-memory or the `HttpResponse.OutputStream`.

Below is some code that shows this off. I **very strongly** recommend separating your PDF logic from your ASPX logic. Do all of you PDF stuff first and get an actual "something" that represents a PDF, then do something with it.

At the beginning we declare a byte array that we'll fill in later. Next we create a `System.IO.MemoryStream` that will be used to write the PDF to. After creating the `Document` we then create a `PdfWriter` that's bound to the `Document` and our stream. Your internal code is the same and although I didn't test it it appears correct. Right before we're done with our `MemoryStream` we grab the active bytes into our byte array. Lastly we use the `BinaryWrite()` method to send our raw binary PDF to the requesting client.

```
//At the end of this bytes will hold a byte array representing an actual PDF file
Byte[] bytes;

//Create a simple in-memory stream
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()){
    using (var doc = new Document()) {

        //Create a new PdfWriter bound to our document and the stream
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)) {
            doc.Open();

            //This is unchanged from the OP's code

            //Sample HTML
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append(@"<p>This is a test: <strong>مسندم</strong></p>");

            //Path to our font
            string arialuniTff = Server.MapPath("~/tradbdo.TTF");
            //Register the font with iTextSharp
            iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(arialuniTff);

            //Create a new stylesheet
            iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
            //Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
            ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Traditional Arabic Bold");
            //Set the default encoding to support Unicode characters
            ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

            //Parse our HTML using the stylesheet created above
            List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString()), ST);

            //Loop through each element, don't bother wrapping in P tags
            foreach (var element in list) {
                doc.Add(element);
            }

            doc.Close();
        }
    }

    //Right before closing the MemoryStream grab all of the active bytes
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

//We now have a valid PDF and can do whatever we want with it

//In this case, use BinaryWrite to send it directly to the requesting client
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
```